# how to detect where the vertical scroll is with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, position

```
if  ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()){
```

This sentence returns true when the scroll it's at, lets say, 'the end' of the scroll bar.

ok,

how could i know when it's on 80% (20% left) ???

I'm trying expresions like:

```
if  ($(window).scrollTop()*2 == $(document).height() - $(window).height()){  // at the middle?
if  ($(window).scrollTop() == ($(document).height() - $(window).height())+100){    /// 100px left?
```

But none of them are ever returning true..

any idea why?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDITED

Look here: http://jsfiddle.net/CoolEsh/aQcBZ/7/

HTML

```
<div style="height:400px;">1 div</div>
<div style="height:300px;">2 div</div>
<div style="height:400px;">3 div</div>
<div style="height:200px;">4 div</div>
<div style="height:600px;">5 div</div>
```

JS

```
var handlerObj = {

    _pageAboveCenter: null,

    init: function()
    {
        handlerObj._pageAboveCenter = handlerObj._isPageAboveCenter();

        $( window ).scroll( handlerObj._handleScroll );
    },

    _handleScroll: function()
    {
        var curentPositionAboveCenter = handlerObj._isPageAboveCenter();
        if ( curentPositionAboveCenter != handlerObj._pageAboveCenter )
        {
            handlerObj._centerIntersection();
            handlerObj._pageAboveCenter = curentPositionAboveCenter;
        }

    },

    _centerIntersection: function()
    {
        console.log( "Center intersected!" ); // this is for firebug console
    },

    _isPageAboveCenter: function()
    {
        if ( ( Math.floor( $( window ).height() / 2 ) + $(window).scrollTop() ) > ( Math.floor( $(document).height() / 2 ) ) )
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}

$( document ).ready( handlerObj.init );
```

This example working event if someone scrolls to fast. I init variable `_pageAboveCenter` on page load. Then on scroll event I check current position (is it above or below center) and if values of `curentPositionAboveCenter` and `handlerObj._pageAboveCenter` are differ then I call method that center was intersected.

Comment: I'm affraid it's not working for me (or in the jdsfile you sent :S). works for you? Thanks a lot for your time!

Comment: Just look and try my jsfiddle. I added coupe divs with height for test puproses. You tried to use wrong calculation logic.

Comment: There is need to make some interval, 4 or 6 pixels for example, where we detect that scroll is on the middle of the page. You may change -2 and +2 at the and of conditions to increase or decrease this interval.

Comment: There is something weir about it! it works, but if you refresh it doesn't work allways! how is this posible?

Comment: There is something with speed of scrolling. If I scroll too fast then event not fired. I'll try to fix it now.

Comment: thank you very muchy! i tried +10 -10 and still got same problem... +50-50?

Comment: Thanks a lot for you inclredible help. but finally i just realised that it won't be a option for me. Because this is also called when you are scrolling UP, wich breaks my thing... but still good to know for future ;)

Comment: But you can update my code to check when document center reached only by scrolling from beginning to the end of the document, like there: http://jsfiddle.net/CoolEsh/aQcBZ/8/